# JQUERY MOBILE to app or apk

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I getting problem here.
I have build a small site with jquery mobile with google map and made it hosted.

I want to make this an app build apk file.

What would i do to make the final apk file?
If the process is long i will manage.
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Comment here to those who also had this problem

Comment: You need to create an Android Studio project with a WebView to display your site -- tutorial here -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hm7rTjM1Sac

Comment: is there another way
because i have tried it on android studio with Webview
it requires some configurations
another way 
so that i can descide which way i should do

Comment: if that is your answer kindly put it as answer

Comment: no there is no other way -- if you find webview a bit hard to understand you can try crosswalk embedding api -- https://crosswalk-project.org/  -- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html

Comment: actually now that i remember i used to this app simply which uses the Google chrome for mobile to work so perhaps you can write your App that way -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.olabs.simply&hl=en

Comment: Thanks :)
thank you for understanding
Last question
for you which is better 
crosswalk, phonegap or ionic. This is my last question
Thank you very much.
you can put your answer down as answer
so i can upvote it

Comment: no problem -- Here is some info about Chrome Custom tabs -- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.cy/2015/09/chrome-custom-tabs-smooth-transition.html

Comment: Wow. so google chrome should be install in that android phone before using app made by that

Comment: I guess so but it comes preinstalled on Android and you cant uninstall it. You may even get Iphone users and whatever else. You can Force stop it or disable it but i dont think many people do that. Just look here at the market share, chrome is number 1 https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=1

Comment: To answer your question -- crosswalk is a replacement for webview, its a cromium browser so it has (almost) everything built in like a normal Crome browser  -- phonegap uses webview or crosswalk -- phonegap enables you to access native api's like a database or video or sound or GPS Location etc etc  -- Ionic, Jquery mobile, google polymer etc etc enable you to create web Apps that look like Native apps, using Javascript / jquery, Html and CSS

Comment: i understand thank you very much
i have now more deeper understanding to those.
God Bless You :)
i wish you could help more people :)